# `FailedToExtractRuntimeVersion` when calling `set_code` during a parachain runtime upgrade

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade

I was updating the runtime via sudo with some specific wasm file.

What is the reason of error while upgrading the runtime?
[image]

Comment: How do you get the WASM code? Which file did you use in the `wbuild` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upgrade the parachain runtime, please use `parachainSystem.authorizeUpgrade`, upload your wasm and then `parachainSystem.enactAuthorizedUpgrade` and upload your wasm.
[image]
[image]